# Does include or require refresh a page? Help on changing .active in nav-bar echoed by PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backend

I have a question on [include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), on whether `require_once something.php` triggers a refresh or not? It seems every new `require` call does trigger a refresh.

Actually, my actual question is something different but it directed my attention to the above. Please bear with a beginner like me.

On [Bootstrap 5 navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/), a nav-items has a `.active` to make it stand out. I want to move the `.active` to the relevant nav-item clicked and tried [this on codepen](https://codepen.io/deanstreet/pen/BaRJOwz?editors=1010). The script works fine, but it doesn't work when using it on my toy website, where the navbar html codes are echoed out by php depending on `$isLoggedIn == true || false`.

The index page is composed of a header.php (which the nav-bar resides) and a requestedPage.php (which includes whatever page being requested).

When a page on the header is clicked, that generates `index.php?reqPage=SomePage` and *included* in index.php by `require_once __DIR__."/pages/$reqPage.php";`, which reloads the page (including header.php), so those nav-bar items start afresh with `.active` in *Home* rather than the item clicked. Whenever I click on a nav-item, the alert *Link clicked!* is first shown followed by *document loaded!*, suggesting `.active` is changed and then nav-bar reloaded.

Please comment and/or advise on how to make the `.active` work. I am new to php and backend.

**files**

```
index.php
header.php
js/header.js
pages/page1.php
pages/page2.php
pages/page3.php...
```

**header.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--bootstrap and jquery CDNs are here-->
    <script src="js/header.js"></script> //for changing .active in nav-item
</head> 
<body>
<?php //use php to echo out the nav-bar
if ($isLoggedIn) { //show bootstrap nav-bar for a logged-in user 
    echo "
        <nav class='navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary'>
        <div class='container'>
        <a class='navbar-brand' href='#'>Trump</a>
        <button class='navbar-toggler' type='button' data-bs-toggle='collapse' data-bs-target='#loggedInMenus'>
        <span class='navbar-toggler-icon'></span>
        </button>
        <div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='loggedInMenus'>
        <ul class='navbar-nav'>
            <li class='nav-item'>
            <a class='nav-link active' href='index.php?reqPage=page1'>Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class='nav-item'>
            <a class='nav-link' href='index.php?reqPage=page2'>Lions</a>
            </li>
            <li class='nav-item'>
            <a class='nav-link' href='index.php?reqPage=page3'>Tigers</a>
            </li>
        </ul></div></div></nav>
    ";
} else { //show nav-bar for an unlogged-in visitor
    echo "
        <nav class='navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary'>
        <div class='container'>
        <a class='navbar-brand' href='#'>Trump</a>
        <button class='navbar-toggler' type='button' data-bs-toggle='collapse' data-bs-target='#unloggedInMenus'>
        <span class='navbar-toggler-icon'></span>
        </button>
        <div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='unloggedInMenus'>
        <ul class='navbar-nav'>
            <li class='nav-item'>
            <a class='nav-link active' href='page1.php'>Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class='nav-item'>
            <a class='nav-link' href='index.php?reqPage=page4'>Dogs</a>
            </li>
            <li class='nav-item'>
            <a class='nav-link' href='index.php?reqPage=page5'>Cats</a>
            </li>
        </ul></div></div></nav>
    ";
}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__."/init.php"; //this contains $isLoggedIn
require_once __DIR__."/header.php"; //load the menus
$reqPage = isset($_REQUEST["reqPage"]) ? $_REQUEST["reqPage"] : null; 
require_once __DIR__."/pages/$reqPage.php"; //load the requested page
```

**header.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert("document loaded!");
  $(".nav-link").on("click", function() {
    alert("Link clicked!");
    $(".navbar-nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    }  
  );
});
```

Comment: Your javascript isn't working because as soon as you click a nav link, the page reloads.  You can do this in the PHP code, possibly by creating your nav menu with a loop

Comment: @jason which is something I don't know how to do. Doesn't most nav-links loads some page, triggering a reload. In other posts, that js is often talked about so I adopted it.

Comment: `whether require_once something.php triggers a refresh or not?`...no. A `require` happens server side, during PHP execution. It cannot trigger a refresh - only a browser can do that. Clicking on your nav link is what triggers the refresh - that sends a request to the webserver, which triggers the PHP script to run, and that PHP script may contain a `require` amongst all the other commands which it executes. Nothing PHP does can directly trigger the browser to refresh the page.

Comment: So then when PHP returns its response back to the browser, the browser displays that new response - i.e. a brand new HTML document. Any changes you made to the previous document using javascript are irrelevant because that document no longer exists in the browser. You'd need to use _PHP_ to work out which page is now the active one, and render the HTML appropriate to give the "active" class to the correct item while it's constructing the HTML.

Comment: @Adyson if I may decipher what you say, I am using php to load a requested page which re-runs the script everytime, but using js to change `.active` before each re-run, so mixing front-end and back-end languages is the source of my idiocy?

Comment: I wouldn't say "idiocy", but perhaps "confusion", yes - we all have to learn the concepts of how web applications work, so it's no reflrection on your general intelligence that you're still at an early stages of that process :-). And yes you're changing something using JS which is then immediately destroyed and replaced by the results of the refresh.

Comment: I think you're trying to get to where you're going two different ways.  Imagine trying to go around the house from both the left and the right.  You should probably rethink your design.  You could either use JS and AJAX to dynamically load the page content, or continue with the server side (PHP) approach.  I'll post some code as an "answer" below, but I don't think it will actually answer your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach uses purely PHP to achieve the goal of setting the "active" class on the correct link.  I don't know if your website is database driven or not, but for simplicity, I'm using an array to store your pages

```
<body>
    <?php
    // DON'T use php to echo out the nav-bar.  Instead just close the PHP tag
    
    $pagesArray = array('page1' => 'Home',
                        'page2' => 'title2',
                        'page3' => 'title3',
                        'page4' => 'Dogs',
                        'page5' => 'Cats');
    
    if ($isLoggedIn) {
    //show bootstrap nav-bar for a logged-in user 
    
    ?>
            <nav class='navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary'>
            <div class='container'>
            <a class='navbar-brand' href='#'>Trump</a>
            <button class='navbar-toggler' type='button' data-bs-toggle='collapse' data-bs-target='#loggedInMenus'>
            <span class='navbar-toggler-icon'></span>
            </button>
            <div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='loggedInMenus'>
            <ul class='navbar-nav'>
    <?php
    // Open PHP tag again
    foreach($pagesArray AS $key => $value){
      //  Loop through your pages array (or sql loop, etc)
      $active = "";
      if ( stripos($reqPage, $key) !== FALSE) {
        //  if $key (page name) matches $reqPage make this link active
        //  if no match, $active remains empty, so when it is echo'ed,
        //  there is no class printed on the page for that anchor tag
        $active = "class='active'";
      }
      echo "<li class='nav-item'>
                <a class='nav-link' ".$active." href='index.php?reqPage=".$key."'>".$value."'</a>
                </li>";
      } // END while loop
        // close PHP tag again
      ?>
      </ul></div></div></nav>
    <?php
    } // END if logged in
    ?>
    </body>
```

Comment: I see your logic and tried to use it in my toy website, but it seems that something is wrong. `header.php` contains the navbar and is included into `index.php` by `require_once header.php`. $reqPage is a variable in `index.php` and seems null in `header.php`, so when I tried to test if `$reqPage == $key` in the loop, it always fails to set `.active`.

Comment: I see the problem.  You are requiring header.php BEFORE you set the variable.  Just move the line $reqPage = isset($_REQUEST["reqPage"]) ? $_REQUEST["reqPage"] : null;  above the line require_once __DIR__."/header.php"; //load the menus and it will work.

Comment: you're right. I didn't pay attention to that sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Given my code organization where the navbar is inside `header.php` and included into `index.php`, and that the requested page variable `$reqPage` only resides in `index.php`, I cannot test $reqPage = $page inside `header.php` to identify the selected page before echoing out each nav-item.

- `$page` exists in `header.php` before echoing out each nav-item
- when user clicks on a link, its value goes to `index.php` as $_GET[""]
- it is assigned to `$reqPage` in `index.php`
- so `$page` and `$reqPage` exist in different places at different times, and cannot be tested before echo out, so testing for equality and then add `.active` to the echo doesn't work

Instead, I echo out the nav-bar in `header.php` and only identify the requested page and then add `.active` in `index.php` using JS.

**header.php**

```
 <nav class='navbar bg-primary'>
        <div class='container'>
        <a class='navbar-brand' href='#'>Trump</a>
        <button class='navbar-toggler' type='button' data-bs-toggle='collapse' data-bs-target='#menus'>
        <span class='navbar-toggler-icon'></span>
        </button>
        <div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='menus'>
        <ul class='navbar-nav'>

<?php //php to dynamically echo out each navbar menu dependent on login 

//array to contain nav-items for logged-in / unlogged-in users
$loggedInMenu = ["Home" => "home", "Lions" => "lions", "Tigers" => "tigers", "Log Out" => "logout"];
$unloggedInMenu = ["Home" => null, "Log In" => "login", "Sign Up" => "signup"]; 

//produce either Logged-in menus or Unlogged-in menus
if ($isLoggedIn) { 
    produceNavMenu($loggedInMenu);
} else { 
    produceNavMenu($unloggedInMenu);
}

//helper function to echo out the nav-menu by nav-items one by one
//@param $menu must be associative array having Title => reqPage
function produceNavMenu(array $menu) {
    foreach($menu as $title => $page) {
        echo "<li class='nav-item'> 
            <a class='nav-link' id='$page' href='index.php?reqPage=$page'>$title</a>
            </li>";
    }
}

?>
        </ul></div></div></nav><!--end of navbar-->
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__."/init.php"; //this contains $isLoggedIn
require_once __DIR__."/header.php"; //load the menus
$reqPage = isset($_REQUEST["reqPage"]) ? $_REQUEST["reqPage"] : null; 
require_once __DIR__."/pages/$reqPage.php"; //load the requested page
?>

<script> //js to add .active to the relevant nav-item
$(document).ready( function() {
  var reqPage = "<?php echo "$reqPage"; ?>"; //php var to js var
  var activeID = "#"+reqPage; //html id
  $(activeID).addClass("active"); //add .active to the requested page
});
</script>
```